# How to use the mutable.AnyRefMap.fromZip?

Tags: scala

This is my code:

```
val nums = (2 to 10).toList
val flags = List.tabulate(nums.size)(_ => 1)
val num_flags = mutable.AnyRefMap.fromZip(nums, flags)
```

It got the exception:

```
cmd6.sc:1: overloaded method value fromZip with alternatives:
  [K <: AnyRef, V](keys: scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[K], values: scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[V])scala.collection.mutable.AnyRefMap[K,V] <and>
  [K <: AnyRef, V](keys: Array[K], values: Array[V])scala.collection.mutable.AnyRefMap[K,V]
 cannot be applied to (List[Int], List[Int])
val num_flags = mutable.AnyRefMap.fromZip(nums, flags)
                                  ^
Compilation Failed.
```

How to use the mutable.AnyRefMap.fromZip ? And why the exception?

Comment: What you're trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I want to create a mutable map from two list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `AnyRefMap.fromZip` method declaration, you'll see the following constraint:

```
K <: AnyRef
```

This means that `K` has to be a subtype of `AnyRef`, where `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`. Thus, the compiler fails, telling you the constraints do not match.

I don't see a reason to use `AnyRefMap` here, if you want a mutable map, just use `mutable.Map`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val keys = (2 to 10).toList
  val values = List.tabulate(nums.length)(_ => 1)
  val numFlags = mutable.Map(keys.zip(values):_*)
}
```